# Sound Volume after boot always at loudest level

Tags: sound, alsa, soundcard, volume-control, indicator-sound

I installed 10.04 a couple of weeks ago. My primary OS is Windows and i could not install Linux up until very recently because of lack of hardware support for my notebook.

10.04 is the only distribution that i managed to get to install on my notebook, but my problem is, that even though i set the volume at a low level, every time after booting and login into Ubuntu, the sounds will play at the highest volume. The volume indicator will still show the low volume setting, but sounds play at the highest volume until i click the volume setting again manually

Is there a config-file i need to update to fix this, or is it a known bug?
Anybody had the same problem?

Comment: Please don't forget to add your hardware specs to this question.

Comment: Probably a bug from ALSA but we need to know what is your sound card to find which one.

Comment: Gio, did you find a solution? I have the same problem on 10.10, and on my system "loud" means 106 db with no hardware volume regulator. Sound card Onkyo Wavio SE-U55SX.

Comment: If it's a bug, this should be reported elsewhere, with all the details, so it can be fixed. I have the same problem with 11.10 (and I think it has come and gone with earlier distributions)

Comment: Try updating alsa, I also had same kind of problem and updated to the latest in my 10.10.It is now fixed (but BUGS are BUGS, now music delays when alert sound plays-not always, Rarely)

Answer (score 2):

Please try [this approach](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=4675606&postcount=4) - it might help.

Answer (score -1):

I think this issue is related to a known bug, that is already in proggress: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/206315

Comment: That specific bug is very old, and very likely fixed now.

Comment: It's not fixed, there are still issues that are associated with it.

Comment: A new bug might be a better way to raise the profile of this, despite some un-tracable reference to it being fixed in git at the end.